# Awaiting task array which is executed in lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, async-await

TestAwaitTaskArrayAsync() can be called from several places in code. I need to lock execution of taskArray and wait asynchronously till its all tasks are finished before next call will start executing taskArray. Here is the code:

```
private async Task TestAwaitTaskArrayAsync()
        {
            Task[] taskArray;
            lock (_lock_taskArray)
            {
              taskArray = new Task[]
              {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    SomeMethod1();
                }),
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    SomeMethod2();
                })
              };
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(taskArray);
        }
```

Await in lock is not allowed so I could use [AsyncLock](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ComparingTwoTechniquesInNETAsynchronousCoordinationPrimitives.aspx) if necessary, but trying keep it simple. Is this code correct and thread safe? I am not sure if await Task.WhenAll(taskArray); can be outside of lock, should I use AsyncLock instead?

Comment: If your `taskArray` is really a local variable then you don't need to lock anything at all.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary, taskArray is local but SomeMethod1() and SomeMethod2() change many variables, so when TestAwaitTaskArrayAsync() is called several Times at the same time then results can be mixed.

Comment: In that case, you may find a better solution with `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` and/or a TPL Dataflow mesh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lock you're using has almost no effect because creating the tasks is very fast and does not conflict with anything. The way you achieve mutual exclusion in an async setting is with the `SemaphoreSlim` class. It is a lock that supports the Task-async pattern.

```
    SemaphoreSlim sem = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
    private async Task TestAwaitTaskArrayAsync()
    {
        await sem.WaitAsync();
        try {
         Task[] taskArray = new Task[]
           {
             Task.Run(() =>
             {
                 SomeMethod1();
             }),
             Task.Run(() =>
             {
                 SomeMethod2();
             })
           };
         }
         await Task.WhenAll(taskArray);
        }
        finally { sem.Release(); }
    }
```

In a synchronous way this would have been easier:

```
lock (_lock_taskArray)
 Parallel.Invoke(() => SomeMethod1(), () => SomeMethod2());
```

Done.

You can also use `AsyncLock` if you like. That should allow you to use the `using` construct to release the lock reliably.

Comment: The question talks about `AsyncLock` (though it doesn't say which one), that would probably work too.

Comment: Also, `SemaphoreSlim` doesn't have parameterless constructor. I think you want `new SemaphoreSlim(1)`. (And of course, fields can't be `var`.)

Comment: @svick Added link to AsyncLock.